# UITableView scroll indicator under UINavigationBar after modifying contentEdgeInset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` that can show data as `UICollectionView` or in `UITableView`. iOS 7 automatically adjust scroll view inset for the first `UIScrollView` founded in the view hierarchy.

So, `UICollectionView` is ok but I have to set `contentEdgeInset` for the `UITableView`. After this line

`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);`

content in `UITableView` are shown well, but the scroll indicator doesn't stop at the `UINavigationBar`, but continue under it.

How can I resolve this and stop the scroll indicator at the begin of `UINavigationBar` ?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also set the `scrollIndicatorInsets` as follows:

```
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

By the way, on iOS 7, you should use `[self.topLayoutGuide length]` instead of hard-coding `44.0f` pixels. From the [iOS 7 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html):

> The topLayoutGuide and bottomLayoutGuide properties indicate the location of the top or bottom bar edges in a view controller’s view.

Comment: Perfect ! But `[self.topLayoutGuide length]` doesn't work for me... return 0. Why ?

Comment: If you're calling it in -viewDidLoad then it may return zero. Best thing to do would be to check it in -viewDidLayoutSubviews and set your insets there.

Comment: also you might want to set content insets as well in viewWillLayoutSubviews itself as below:
`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 49.0f, 0.0f);`